# Getting incorrect equation of circle passing through two points and a line passing through the center of the circle.

Tags: geometry, circles, conic-sections

After an unsuccessful search for the answer to my math problem I came here to ask my question. I am trying to find the **equation of circle** but having a difficulty.

The Problem is as follows:
**Find the Equation of Circle which passes through the points A(1, -2), B(4,3) and has its center on the line 3x+4y-7=0.**

I want to solve it by two methods. I was able to solve it by the first method but got different values in the 2nd method.

### My Approach using the first method:

let the required equation of circle be $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2$$

[I draw this as a rough diagram so you guys can understand better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxrvS.jpg)

Here in the above diagram: $$|AO| = |BO|$$
$$=> \sqrt{((-g)-1)^2 + ((-f)+2)^2 } = \sqrt{((-g)-4)^2 + ((-f)-3)^2 }$$

let (h,k) = (-g,-f) then

$$=> \sqrt{(h-1)^2 + (k+2)^2 } = \sqrt{(h-4)^2 + (k-3)^2 }$$

Squaring both sides of the above equations
$$=> (\sqrt{(h-1)^2 + (k+2)^2 })^2 = (\sqrt{(h-4)^2 + (k-3)^2 })^2$$
Therefore $$=>h^2+1-2h+k^2+4+4k = h^2+16-8h+k^2+9-6k$$
$$=> -6h-10k+20=0$$
$$=> 3h+5k-10=0------(i)$$
**Given Equation of Line is $$3x+4y-7=0------(ii)$$**
$$(ii)=> 3h+4k-7=0 $$  **(As the line passes through the center of the circle) and

C(-g,-f) = C(h,k)**

$$(i)=> 3h+5k=10$$
$$(ii)=> 3h+4k=7$$

Now Solving (i) and (ii) simultaneously to find the coordinates of the center of the circle

**Subtract (ii) from (i)**

Therefore $$3h+5k=10$$ 
$$-   (3h+4k)=-(7)$$
$$-----------$$ 
$$k = 3$$
**Put k=3 in equation (i)** 
$$(i)=> 3h+5(3)=10$$ 
$$=> h = -5/3$$
**Now finding the radius of the Circle:**
$$|AO| = r = \sqrt{(-5/3 - 4)^2 + (3-3)^2}$$ 
$$=> r = -5/3 - 4$$
$$=> r = -17/3$$
**Now we can find the circle by using standard form** 
that is $$(x-h)^2(y-k)^2 = r^2$$ 
$$=> (x+5/3)^2 + (y-3)^2 = (17/3)^2$$ 
$$=> x^2+25/9+10x/3+y^2+9-6y = 289/9$$ 
$$=> x^2+y^2+10x/3-6y = 289/9-25/9-9$$ 
$$=> x^2+y^2+10x/3-6y = 183/9$$
$$=> x^2+y^2+10x/3-6y-183/9= 0 $$ **(Multiply both sides by 3)**
$$=> 3x^2+3y^2+10x-18y-183/3= 0 $$ 
**Required Equation of Circle is** $ 3x^2+3y^2-10x-18y-61= 0 $

### My Approach using the 2nd method:

**In this method I used general form of equation of the circle to derive the two equations w.r.t 2 points on the circle A and B.**
General Form of equation of Circle: $$x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$ 
for point A(1,-2) on the circle, general form is reduced to: $$1+4+2g-4f+c=0$$ 
$$=> 2g-4f+c = -5 -----(i) $$
for point B(4,3) on the circle, general form is reduced to: $$16+9+8g+6f+c=0$$ 
$$=> 8g+6f+c = -25-----(ii)$$ 
**equation of line** = $3x+4y-7=0 => -3g-4f=7 => 3g+4f=-7 -----(iii)$

**(i), (ii) and(iii) forms a system of linear equations in 3 variables (g,f and c), we need to find those three variable for that reason we write the above the equation in matrix form**

$$ A= \begin{bmatrix}2&-4&1\\8&6&1\\3&4&0\end{bmatrix} X= \begin{bmatrix}g\\f\\c\end{bmatrix} B= \begin{bmatrix}-5\\-25\\-7\end{bmatrix} $$

**Writing in Augmented form**

$$[A|b] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & -4 & 1 & -5 \\
    8 & 6 & 1 & -25 \\
    3 & 4 & 0 & -7
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Now we have to write the above [A|b] in echelon form to find g, f and c and then put them in the general form of the circle in order to get the equation of the circle...This is the step where it give me the wrong answer can you guys check what am I doing wrong?

Edit: ** Credit goes to David in the answer below. There were two minor mistakes pointed out by @David as I wrote 7 instead of -7 in augmented matrix and in **$$(x-(-5/3))^2+(y-3)^2$$

I wrote $$(x-5/3)$$ instead of $$(x+5/3)$$

Comment: If a circle passes through points A,B, the center of the circle is on the perpendicular bisector of the line segment AB. That is all you need. They provide a second line, the intersection of the two lines is the center of the circle. The radius is the distance from the center to either of A,B

Comment: @Will your approach is definitely okay but I was trying to ask that  why I cannot get the same equation of circle in the 2nd method I showed. I correctly converted the above Augmented Matrix into echelon form but the equation of circle was different from method 1, It must be the same.

Comment: You changed $-7$ to $7$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$[A|b] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & -4 & 1 & -5 \\
    8 & 6 & 1 & -25 \\
    3 & 4 & 0 & -7
  \end{array}\right]
$$

$$[A_1|b_1] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    2 & -4 & 1 & -5 \\
    3 & 4 & 0 & -7 \\
    8 & 6 & 1 & -25
  \end{array}\right]\tag{Exchange row 2 with 3}
$$

$$[A_2|b_1] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -4  & -5 \\
    0 & 3 & 4 &  -7 \\
    1 & 8 & 6 &  -25
  \end{array} \right]\tag{Exchange column 2 with 3}
$$

Now $X=\begin{bmatrix}c\\g\\f\end{bmatrix}$

$$[A_3|b_2] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -4  & -5 \\
    0 & 3 & 4 &  -7 \\
    0 & 6 & 10 &  -20
  \end{array}\right]\tag{$1^\mathrm{st}$ step of reduction}
$$

$$[A_4|b_3] =
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -4  & -5 \\
    0 & 3 & 4 &  -7 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 &  -6
  \end{array}\right]\tag{$2^\mathrm{nd}$ step of reduction}
$$

$$\begin{bmatrix}c\\g\\f\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-\frac{61}{3}\\\frac{5}{3}\\-3\end{bmatrix}\tag{Answer}$$

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your first attempt.

You determined that the center of the circle is at $(h,k) = \left(-\frac53, 3\right)$
and the radius is $\frac{17}3$.
Then you wrote the equation

$$
\left(x - \frac53\right) + (y−3)^2 = \left(\frac{17}3\right)^2.
$$

But $x - \left(- \frac53\right)^2 = x + \frac53,$ so the equation for the circle is actually
$$
\left(x + \frac53\right)^2 + (y−3)^2 = \left(\frac{17}3\right)^2.
$$

---

In your second attempt, what you have shown is correct almost to the end.
Indeed,

$$
A^{-1}b = \begin{pmatrix} 2& -4 & 1 \\ 8 & 6 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 0 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}  \begin{pmatrix} -5 \\ -25 \\ -7\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} \frac53 \\ -3 \\ -\frac{61}3\end{pmatrix},
$$

which is the correct result.
But for some reason, as noted in a comment you have $7$ instead of $-7$ when you built the augmented matrix.
That's definitely going to cause a wrong result.

Comment: Thanks @David for pointing that out! I might have forgotten that (h-(-g) )^2= h+g but it only changes one term's sign from negative to positive in my equation that term is 10x.

Comment: Actually I am having trouble in the Second Attempt can you give it a try using the second method?

Comment: @YNK solved it correctly thanks for your corrections in the question. I appreciate you giving your precious time to this and now I am confident with the answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The equation of the circle needs 
the coordinates of its center $O$ and the radius $R$.

Given two points $A(1,-2),\ B(4,3)$ 
on the circle and one line, 
\begin{align}
f_1(x)&=-\tfrac34\,x+\tfrac74
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}

which contains the center of the circle,
we need to know another line that runs through the center.
This line is the line $MO:\ MO\perp AB$,

\begin{align}
M&=\tfrac12(A+B)=(\tfrac52,\tfrac12)
.
\end{align}

The equation of the line $MO$ is found as

\begin{align}
f_2(x)&=-\tfrac35\,(x-\tfrac52)+\tfrac12
=-\tfrac35\,x+2
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

And the center $O$ is easily found at the intersection of  \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}

\begin{align}
O&=(-\tfrac53,3)
.
\end{align}

Since the points $B$ and $O$ have the same $y$-coordinate,
$B_y=O_y=3$,
the radius is found simply as 
\begin{align} 
R&=B_x-O_x=4-(-\tfrac53)=\tfrac{17}3
,
\end{align}

and the equation of the circle is

\begin{align}
(x+\tfrac53)^2+(y-3)^2&=(\tfrac{17}3)^2
.
\end{align}

Comment: Your answer was thorough and explained really nicely but it was already suggested  by @Will jagy in the comment above. I actually did found the equation of circle but what I wanted to achieve was to find the center coordinates and radius by finding the three unknowns in general form using the method #2 in my question, that is x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0 and the radius by r=√(g^2+f^2-c)